# Error installing ruby 1.9.3 from rvm on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

Error

> ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #extracted to /home/bhaarat/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0
>
> Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/bhaarat/.rvm/archives Extracting
> yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/bhaarat/.rvm/src Configuring yaml in
> /home/bhaarat/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
>
> Compiling yaml in
> /home/bhaarat/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4. ERROR: Error running 'make ',
> please read /home/bhaarat/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.log
> Installing yaml to /home/bhaarat/.rvm/usr ERROR: Error running 'make
> install', please read
> /home/bhaarat/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p0/yaml/make.install.log

make.log

```
[2012-01-12 10:49:57] make 
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/bash /home/bhaarat/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing --run aclocal-1.11 
configure.ac:27: warning: AC_INIT: not a literal: YAML_BUGS
 cd . && /bin/bash /home/bhaarat/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing --run automake-1.11 --foreign
configure.ac:27: warning: AC_INIT: not a literal: YAML_BUGS
src/Makefile.am:2: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:2:   The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL'
src/Makefile.am:2:   to `configure.ac' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf' again.
src/Makefile.am:2:   If `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL' is in `configure.ac', make sure
src/Makefile.am:2:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

I've removed all previous versions of ruby

```
% rvm list rubies

rvm rubies
```

Comment: did you run: sudo aptitude install build-essential && sudo aptitude install linux-headers-`uname -r` ?

Comment: Got the same error on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 14):

Try installing the libtool package. I had the same issue and that fixed it. If you're in Ubuntu then it's probably:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

Comment: This also solves the issue installing ruby-1.9.2p290 via rvm 1.14.1 on Ubuntu 11.04. Thanks!